# Error while deploying Unity app ( Connectivity.dll' is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly. )

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, hololens

When I try to deploy my Unity app on the HoloLens Gen1 via USB, I get an error message I don't know how to deal with.

The error message says: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.20279.0\x86\Microsoft.Tools.Connectivity.dll' is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly.

Additionally I get an Bootstrap error.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever deploy any application to the hololens? I'm wondering about the USB connection, it might be nice to start checking the connectivity (e.g. go to https://127.0.0.1:10080 in your browser).

You might need to check whether some workloads(e.g. USB Device Connectivity etc.) is installed to visual studio

See also:
"Connecting over USB" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-the-windows-device-portal

"Installing Visual Studio 2019" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools?tabs=unity

Comment: The problem was that I had several Visual Studio Versions installed. After uninstall all of them and reinstalling VS 2019, I could upload the App.